# About the executable paths in CentOS or any Linux machine

Tags: linux, centos, vim, vi

I have installed vim in my computer, and i see there are two executables in my OS, one is in /usr/local/bin and the other is in /usr/bin. I want to use the /usr/bin vim but, whenever I type vim it takes the /usr/local/bin which I don't want. So, inorder to set the PATH of vim as /usr/bin instead of /usr/local/bin. How can I do that? Because, the vim in the /usr/local/bin is not that great, I mean it acts like vi editor.

Thanks

Comment: How did you install Vim? If you used a package manager (e.g. yum, pacman, apt-get), the one in /usr/bin is it. If you installed it yourself from source, it's probably the one in /usr/local/bin. In any case, there would appear to be two of them there, and I wonder if they're also using two different config files (e.g. /etc/vimrc vs /usr/local/etc/vimrc). It could be that the /etc one is configured to use vi compatibility mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your shell. If you're using bash, you can put `/usr/bin` at the start of your PATH by adding the following to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Questions like these are better suited for [unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), by the way.

Comment: Normally /usr/local/bin comes before /usr/bin in your $PATH, so you can override packaged programs with ones you've installed from source. Whether this matters to the OP I don't know. It might be best to just uninstall the one that's not desired.

Comment: I agree with @echristopherson; this answer solves a local problem by introducing a global one (i.e. the inability to override packaged programs).

Answer (score 1):

Programs installed and maintained by your distribution's package manager go into `/usr/bin`; stuff in `/usr/local/bin` is for manually (compiled and) installed applications. I don't know how you got your Vim version there, but as it probably isn't updated automatically and you don't like it, just remove (or rename if you're timid) it:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/vim
```

There may also be corresponding runtime files in `/usr/local/share/vim`; you can remove them as well, though they won't do any harm, just waste disk space.